# ItemUpdated not changing field values

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, itemupdated

I have a document library that should replace the `Name` column with the value from an `Employee` column.

Code:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    try
    {
        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        SPFieldUser employee = item.Fields.GetField("Employee") as SPFieldUser;
        SPFieldUserValue current = employee.GetFieldValue(item["Employee"].ToString()) as SPFieldUserValue;
        if (!item.Name.StartsWith(item.DisplayName))
        {
            item["Name"] = current.User.Name.Replace(", ", "_");
            item["Letter"] = current.User.Name.Substring(0, 1);
        }
        item.Update();
    }
    catch(SPException error)
    {
        throw new SPException(error.Message);
    }
}
```

The when a new document is uploaded and the `Employee` field is entered, the `Name` field is correctly set. However, if you go back and edit the item the `Name` field doesn't change.

Why would this code only work on creation and not update? Better yet, what is missing to get the code to work on both creation and edit?

Comment: A sidenote: Wouldn't this cause an endless loop?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it would.

Comment: 1) fired after the item is updated, `EventFiringEnabled` is not set to `false`. 2) Same item is updated. 3) Triggers an _updated_ event; go to 1)...

Comment: Yeah, you need to disable the event firing

Comment: @Colbs so are you saying that is the answer? Better yet...where to disable event firing?

Comment: it could be. Let's give that a try (I'll post code). Are you getting any errors in that catch? When you say it works on 'Creation', does that mean another event (ItemAdding)?

Comment: Nope, no errors on catch. That's why I was confused about the endless loop conversation. I'm not doing anything with ItemAdding since that wouldn't capture the value from the Employee field (people and group column type).

Comment: Alright, hopefully my code fixes it for you. Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks that may help:

1. You may have an endless loop since the call to .Update triggers itself a new update and then the Event Receiver... You may not notice it immediately since SharePoint 2013 has now a protection that stops the re-entrance after 10 occurrences...
   Simply add `EventFiringEnabled = false;` at the begin of your `ItemUpdated` method and then `EventFiringEnabled = true;` in a `finally` block at the end.
2. `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is most probably not needed here since you work on the contextual `SPWeb` object (i.e. you did not create it explicitely), issued from a POST request. In this case, you don't have to bother with `AllowUnsafeUpdates`.
3. The column 'Name' is the standard Text field from a document Library, right?
4. You should add some `null` checks, for instance `item["Employee"]` may be null and raise an exception with `item["Employee"].ToString()`.
5. I don't understand your `if (!item.Name.StartsWith(item.DisplayName))`... What's the point?
6. To progress on this problem, you definitely need to attach the Visual Studio debugger to w3wp while running the test. This will allow you to ensure:

   - The event receiver is called on an properties update (I guess it is, according to your description)
   - Where it fails, and what's the error message.

Comment: I got my issue fixed, but this is an outstanding answer.

Answer (score 2):

Few changes here...Add the DisabledEvents class and allow unsafe updates. Also if you set the properties.ErrorMessage, it will show in the UI if there is an issue.

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    try
    {
        using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
        {
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            SPFieldUser employee = item.Fields.GetField("Employee") as SPFieldUser;
            SPFieldUserValue current = employee.GetFieldValue(item["Employee"].ToString()) as SPFieldUserValue;
            if (!item.Name.StartsWith(item.DisplayName))
            {
                item["Name"] = current.User;
                item["Letter"] = current.User.Name.Substring(0, 1);
            }
            item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            item.Update();
            item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = error.Message;
    }
}


class DisabledEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
{
    // Boolean to hold the original value of the EventFiringEnabled property 
    bool _originalValue;

    public DisabledEventsScope()
    {
        // Save off the original value of EventFiringEnabled 
        _originalValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;

        // Set EventFiringEnabled to false to disable it 
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Set EventFiringEnabled back to its original value 
        base.EventFiringEnabled = _originalValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you break and step through it in VS? These things can be hard to reattach sometimes. It may have to do with your casting and field types

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now. Thanks for the help by the way...

Comment: Yes, Np. Is the "Name" field a Single line of text?

Comment: No, it's of type Person or Group.

Comment: Well that's your problem. You're trying to set a Person field with a string that would def throw an error on .Update()
I'll make the casting change for you