# How to disable an event firing

Tags: csom, shareoint

I have a document library and inside that i have a hierarchy of  folders.I have made a column named "doc" of type hyperlink or picture. if the folder contain items, the doc column will get an image.

There is an event handler which prevent to make any changes in the list(item updating or item adding).

Now i am writing a console application to remove this doc field value for all the lists(since i have many lists).But getting an error and error is pointing to that event handler.(since the event handler is preventing to make any changes in the list).

Is there any way to disable this event handler and delete this field.

here is my code :

```
 foreach (string libName in allLibraries)
 {
    List oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libName);
    ListItemCollection listItems = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    context.Load(listItems);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
    {
       item["docs"] = new FieldUrlValue() { Url = "", Description = "" };
       item.Update();

       AddLogs("Removed file icon for folder : " + item["FileRef"]);
    }
    context.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using CSOM, there is no way to prevent event receivers from firing. That's the quick answer.

Longer answer. Options:

1) Rewrite your CSOM code into SSOM and wrap it in by `using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())` as @Evariste suggested.

2) Update your document event `ItemUpdating` receiver to add logic similar to this:

```
if(properties.BeforeProperties["docs"] != properties.AfterProperties["docs"])
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.AfterProperties["docs"]))
  {
    // Someone is just trying to clear docs value. let them do it:
    return;
  }
}
```

If you update the original event receiver with the logic above you can go on using your CSOM solution with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (code taken from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/121477/35604, credits go to @Colbs)

```
class DisabledEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
{
    // Boolean to hold the original value of the EventFiringEnabled property 
    bool _originalValue;

    public DisabledEventsScope()
    {
        // Save off the original value of EventFiringEnabled 
        _originalValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;

        // Set EventFiringEnabled to false to disable it 
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Set EventFiringEnabled back to its original value 
        base.EventFiringEnabled = _originalValue;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
    {
                foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
                {
                    item["docs"] = new FieldUrlValue() { Url = "", Description = "" };
                    item.Update();

                    AddLogs("Removed file icon for folder : " + item["FileRef"]);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Does it actually work with CSOM? it seems that you are mixing server-side object model along with CSOM. Unless I'm missing something, I don't think it's possible to prevent events from firing if you are using CSOM

Comment: Oops… My bad! I don't remove the answer since it may help someone else, but, yeah, I read the question too quickly, sorry. With CSOM, as you stated, there's no way to do it.